# Dual boot broken after using TestDisk

Tags: windows, boot, grub

I messed around with [TestDisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestDisk) after loosing some important data and ended up ruining my whole system (dual boot, and I cannot boot to either). I can only see this screen:
[image]

Even when I managed to get into BIOS and change the configuration (from uefi to legacy) or the boot order as some people recommended, it still did not work as there was no boot device detected.

At this point I had to make a bootable-usb to boot. I used one with [boot/repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). I tried various repairing configurations but none of them worked. After various changes, I no longer think my Ubuntu system can be recovered tbh (The Ubuntu partitions show up as an unused memory space) but my Windows system seems to be there and fine; I can access it from the live boot but I just cannot boot to it. This is the [BOOT REPAIR REPORT](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YJkDmDvyBV/) **maybe someone here more knowledgeable than me, can recommend some solution or some sort of magic to fix this.** BTW this is how my disk looks like right now:
[image]

I should mention that I tried to install Ubuntu in the unused space in an attempt to get something to work but that failed in the last 75% with the following error:
[image]

Also in a similar fashion/ desperate attempt I tried to install Windows on top of all hoping it will fix some of the issues, but I could not install it to the unused space nor were I able to even partition the space under Windows.
**I am open to any suggestion at this point?** I already tried singing to my laptop but it still did not work.

*As for the moral of the story: backup, re-backup and backup the backups.

Comment: <Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda' failed. This is a fatal error> as the image shows.

Answer (score 1):

> I am open to any suggestion at this point?

Here's one.

You can back up your remaining files because you say

> my Windows system seems to be there and fine; I can access it from the live boot

So that should be your **first priority**. Copy to a new hard disk all files that are important to you.

Then nuke the whole disk from orbit* and do a fresh install of your preferred operating system. If necessary throw out the hard disk and install a new one. This may be preferable because you can set the old one aside for future recovery attempts.

Finally restore your important files from the backup you made earlier.

> As for the moral of the story: backup, re-backup and backup the backups.

That is certainly worth repeating.

Also occasionally (regularly) test your backups contain what you think they should. Ideally, test recovery from backup so that you are familiar with the process and know for certain that it produces a usable and complete system.

---

* At least delete all partitions and retry installing your desired operating system over the whole device. Let it do whatever partitioning it chooses.

Comment: That's actually my intent, I am just waiting for my new SSD to arrive. As for the backup, I am not sure how to go about it :/ only my Windows C:/ seems to be there, so I intend to copy it to the new drive. tho I will preserve the data, I won't be able to pick my Windows from where I left I think. Do you recommend any better alternatives?

Comment: @SuperKogito: I don't think it wise to copy all of C: I would keep the backup device separate from any device you intend to install an operating system on.